# How to convert a TextInput to a float for a mapview with Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to convert a textinput to float please..

Currently i've this code :

```
TextInput:
    id: latitude1
    multiline: False
    pos_hint: {"x":0.16, "top":0.5}
    input_filter:"float"
```

.....

```
Button:
    pos_hint: {"x":0.08, "top":0.8}
    text: "Modify map"
    on_press: mapview1.center_on(longitude1,latitude1)
```

I have already replaced the parameters `mapview1.center_on(longitude1,latitude1)` by `mapview1.center_on(46.02,3.02)` in order to test if the button works well, and it works perfectly and the map refresh with the news coords!

On the other hand, when the parameters are like: `mapview1.center_on(longitude1,latitude1)`, I get this error:

```
File "kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 70, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__richcmp__
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'TextInput' and 'float'.
```

I don't understand how to convert TextInput directly to Float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `latitude1` is a reference to the `TextInput` `Widget`. The actual text will be `latitude1.text`. To convert it to a `float`, use the `float()` function:

```
float(latitude1.text)
```

So your `on_press` should be something like:

```
on_press: mapview1.center_on(float(longitude1.text),float(latitude1.text))
```